# Tips to improve questions to attract more answers

Tags: discussion

I have posted some questions which were not well received. Nothing new as I've received tumbleweed badge earlier also. I'd like advises on how to improve them so that I can attract more answers. The questions were not down voted, so maybe there's some other problem.

Those questions are here

[How is voltage induced in Yd transformer without neutral connection sinusoidal?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/461592/64230)

[Why do we require isolated supplies for gate drivers in 3-phase inveters?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/467951/64230)

[What will happen if the prime mover driving synchronous machine is accidentally disconnected?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/469238/64230)

Upon trying to self-diagonise the issue it looks to me that it is because

1. The site's primary focus is on low-voltage low-power electronics design and not on high-power high-voltage machines.
2. The questions which I asked were not *very* simple, of course simple electronics design question receives more answers, understandably so.
3. I tend to write too much, I am not good at concise writing, English is not my first language.
4. I'm yet a student and all questions which weren't well answered were mostly theoretical whereas site is more about helping practising engineers.

Regardless I'd like advices for bettering them and my future questions. Thank you!

Comment: Oh and android app is buggy, there's no reason for my points 3 & 4 to be misaligned. It's not me, it's app.

Comment: Seems like your presentation is the problem ...

Comment: @Mitu raj ...... tips?

Comment: It's also notable that.. Questions related with microcontrollers, digital and analog circuits are most popular here.

Comment: Length questions without any illustrations or specificity may cause users to ignore it.

Comment: Yes I agree with both, it's just that app is way too buggy, never allows me to upload a picture from device. Also the site doesn't has large population of people inclined towards high power stuff...

Comment: Am using Android app. I have options to upload pic in question

Comment: I too have an option, the uploading from device never finishes though, I have to make some fake account (cause I forgot earlier one) on tumblr or tinypic (which is now dead), upload image there, copy img url and paste it here, too much efforts... I went to Play Store to reviews this, and there people were complaining that they can't even login without 4-5 attempts.... ironical for the site which hosts most talanted (shall I say rude also?) community of programmers...

Comment: I often feel that I end up hitting your #2 and #3 when trying to ask a question. The process of trying to simplify things and getting to the point is educational even though I often fail...

Comment: There are not many power engineers that frequent the site, your questions are well received as they have been upvoted, they probably haven't been seen by enough people that are most familiar with the subjects in the questions. You can check the tags (notice that in the last 8 days 40% of the questions in the transformers tag have been unanswered) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/transformer/topusers

Comment: @voltage spike wow that looks surprising to me.